# how do I validate a user input in a Textbox against a column from a SQL Server table

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I did my homework prior to asking this questions. Though, none of the results that google showed  functioned .

I have a textbox whose input I wish to validate against a list of values which exist in a column of a table (ASP.NET with C# and SQL Server 2014 Express) . Should user enter some other value, than the error must be displayed.

I have done multiple tryouts with CustomValidator control and one when an event on the Textbox (.TextChanged). But I lost something, may be in the details. Could you give me a practical solution and at best, guide towards a useful online resource to study the connection to databases from asp.net (c#)?

I am aware that I did not catch the subject.

Comment: Please can you post your View and how you are getting the values from the DB i your post.

Comment: You could use jquery to get the values and also to check for the change. Or if you're already retrieving the values then simply use jquery to check the text. you can see here how to do this : http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/

Comment: I don't know why you are using text box then... If you want your user to select data which is in column...
You can use a drop down list...

Comment: there are too many values the user should select from. about 60 000 possible items in the list. is it feasible to use the drop down list for so many? thanks

Comment: @George that's a lot of data...
You can't use drop down :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a basic rough version how you could get it done. Can also use a Stored procedure rather than direct..Wasn't sure if you meant after a button was clicked or not, but you can put this in a method and have it return true or false if its valid.

```
        SqlConnection cnn = null;
        SqlCommand cmd = null;
        SqlDataAdapter sda = null;
        DataTable Dt = new Datatable();

        cnn = new SqlConnection(strConnectionString);
        cmd = new SqlCommand("Select COLUMN FROM WHEREVER WHERE VALUE =@TextboxValue", cnn);
        cnn.Open();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@TextboxValue", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Textbox.Text;
        sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        sda.Fill(dt);

       if (dt.rows.count > 0 ) 
        {
           //MATCH FOUND
        }
```

Comment: thank you very much for the solution. sorry, but I am beginner in C#. where in the code does it point to the database/table? how should i put it? I mean I have some index.aspx page and some index.aspx.cs which is linked to the previous page. there will be a web.config which states the connectionstring, right. how should i bind all of these? sorry for being silly, I am going to study all of these soon, though I need to have things done in a matter of days. you help is much appreciated. thanks, once more

Comment: Put the connection string in the web config like you said. Put this code in the .cs file in a method somewhere, once the button is clicked, call this method, if it matches either let them know by redirecting them to another page, or whatever you want. If it doesn't match, dont let them through and make a label or a validator say something to know it's incorrect. I can help you more if you need, just let me know.